# Unable to log in as new created user in Oracle 11g

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I recently made a new tablespace and associated a user with it (sonar).

Currently, a copy and paste of the user profile looks like this:

```
Name    SONAR
Profile DEFAULT
Authentication  Password
Default Tablespace  SONAR
Temporary Tablespace    TEMP
Status  UNLOCK
Default Consumer Group  None


Role    Admin Option    Default
CONNECT N   Y
DBA N   Y
RESOURCE    N   Y


System Privilege    Admin Option
CREATE SESSION  N
UNLIMITED TABLESPACE    N
```

I can log in to the OEM console with this new user but am unable to connect to the sonar tablespace with that user. I know the connection properties I'm using are valid because I can connect with other users and view their tablespaces.

So, does anyone have an idea what I might be missing that is preventing me from connecting with this user and using their default tablespace? If I need to provide any more information, let me know. I'm not very experienced with DBA stuff.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "connect to the sonar tablespace"?  You connect to a database instance, not to a tablespace.  What is the command that is failing and what is the Oracle error that is being thrown.

Comment: Well, if I have the tablespace created, how would I create a database instance of that to connect to? I'm guessing that's part my problem (that or incorrect terminology)? I'm using SQL developer to connect, so I'm just putting in the connect parameters as properties of a connection. My error is this: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Comment: A tablespace is just a collection of data files-- you don't connect to it.  You connect to the database instance.  It sounds like you are connecting to a database instance but the password is incorrect.  One thing that threw people is that passwords became case-sensitive by default in 11g.  Is it possible that you're entering the password with the incorrect casing in SQL Developer?

Comment: I can't imagine why it would be so. I made sure the password was correct a few times. I should note, if I try to connect to a different user for that instance, I can do so. If I don't supply a password, I get a warning that the password is null. However, if I try to connect to sonar without a password, I don't get that null warning, which makes me think it isn't recognizing sonar as a valid user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're getting an "ORA-01017: invalid username/ password" error, there are only a handful of possibilities

1. The password specified in SQL Developer is wrong.
2. The username specified in SQL Developer is wrong.
3. The password you're typing is correct but the tool is passing the wrong password to the database.  When 11g made passwords case-sensitive by default, many tools hiccuped because they hadn't been preserving the casing in the passwords that were stored.  I have no recollection of any version of SQL Developer being affected by this problem but if you have an old version, it's probably worth upgrading to the newly released 3.0 version anyway.
4. The database you are connecting to is not the database where you created the `Sonar` user.  If you can connect as other users using the same connection information, can you query `DBA_USERS` and verify that you see the `Sonar` user?

Comment: I am able to see the sonar user in DBA_USERS. I am using the latest x64 version of SQL Developer. I tried all possible lower and upper case versions of my very short password and username. I tried creating another user and have the same problem. Perhaps I'll try it through the command line. I'm pretty stumped.

Comment: Sounds like you aren't connecting to the right database then. Presumably when you look at `DBA_USERS` you're connecting differently, not using the same connection from SQL Developer?

Comment: I'm connecting via a different user but with the same connection properties in SQL Developer. That's where I ran the select on dba_users. However, when I connect via SQL plus I'm getting a different result from querying dba_users, so you are right, I muts be connecting to the wrong database somehow. I'll try to figure out what the discrepancy is but at least now I know the problem. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Hah, yes, I just figured it out. Our team had recently switched databases and the documentation I was reading was out of date so I was creating user in the new database but trying to connect to the old one. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

Just a note that I had a similar issue with Oracle 19c and the problem turned out to be that the username consisted of lower case letters. I had to change it to upper case and then it would work.

- I had created a user called "pm_bool" with SQL Developer and could not log in with it through SQL Developer or SQLplus.
- Then I created the user as "PM_BOOL" with SQL Developer. After that both ways of logging in worked fine.

Comment: This was also my problem, the tool creating the user wasn't passing in the correct casing during login. Very annoying, but got there in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bug in the SQL Developer Software. A work around would be to create the user through SQL Commandline[Instructions: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/admin.112/e18585/toc.htm#XEGSG114 ]

After having created the user in the command line, create the connection in the SQL Developer and it works

Answer (score 0):

"Old" post, but I figured out that I had another root cause for this issue : I created the user with user SYS (created when installing my DB instance), and connected using SQLDeveloper as "SYSADMIN" role. I then tried to connect with my new user, but did not change the "role" in my connection. It seems it "sticks" to the initial role defined when the connection is created.
I reverted it back to "default" with the new user and the connection went through.